# what is the use of tokens.h when I am programming a lexer?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am programming a lexer in C and I read somewhere about the header file `tokens.h`. Is it there? If so, what is its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tokens.h` is a file generated by `yacc` or `bison` that contains a list of tokens within your grammar.

Your `yacc`/`bison` input file may contain token declarations like:

```
%token INTEGER
%token ID
%token STRING
%token SPACE
```

Running this file through `yacc`/`bison` will result in a `tokens.h` file that contains preprocessor definitions for these tokens:

```
/* Something like this... */
#define INTEGER (1)
#define ID      (2)
#define STRING  (3)
```

Comment: so how am i supposed to use it?.. do u have any links ?

Comment: no i am not . i am programming my own lex. can you recommend some books on it?

Comment: When did that change?  Last I used them, yacc  output y.tab.c and y.tab.h files.  Bison replaced the 'y' by the source file basename.

Comment: @mekasperasky, yacc (and bison which is the GNU rewriting of yacc) are parser generators.  If you write a lexer which isn't supposed to interface with them, you don't have to know about them.  "Lex and Yacc" by John R. Levine is a well known book about that tools.

Comment: Right.  If you're hand-rolling a lexer, you don't have to worry about tokens.h.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `tokens.h` is a file generated by the parser generator (Yacc/Bison) containing token definitions so you can return tokens from the lexer to the parser.

With Lex/Flex and Yacc/Bison, it works like this:

`parser.y`:

```
%token FOO
%token BAR

%%

start: FOO BAR;

%%
```

`lexer.l`:

```
%{
#include "tokens.h"
%}

%%

foo {return FOO;}
bar {return BAR;}

%%
```